# Root finding: Is there no bisection method root finder?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, syntax, numerical-value

I am trying to find a root to an equation `f[k,...]==0` numerically, where k is the variable I am solving for. Using both `NSove` as well as `FindRoot` I get the Error: `Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t$50961 == 0'.`

I am not sure why it talks about `t` in the error message, since the variable I am solving for is named `k`. `t` is the time variable of an integration which is performed inside of the function `f`. But for the root finding algorithm that should not be important.

Anyway, I thought that the algorithms Mathematica is trying to apply might not be suited to solve my equation. I thought that nothing could go wrong with the bisection method, but I cannot find it precoded in Mathematica.

I know that it is not hard to code it up. But is there really no precoded bisection method already available?

Thanks!

Comment: `f[k,...]==0` ?, I don't see any equation ? It's impolite of you to expect an answer without providing the code to reproduce.

Comment: Dear Mariusz, The function `f` which I have written here is a very complicated procedure, which I cannot plug into this forum. The core question is simple and foesn't require knowledge of this function: "Is there a bisection method precoded in Mathematica, yes or no?" I really do not think that is impolite to ask.

Comment: There's `Method -> "Brent"` but not a bisection method. One can consider [Brent's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method) an improvement of the bisection method. Search this site if you really want an implementation of the bisection method.  Others have written some code for it.

Comment: As shown in the documentation, "FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, Subscript[x, 0], Subscript[x, 1]}] searches for a solution using Subscript[x, 0] and Subscript[x, 1] as the first two values of x, avoiding the use of derivatives."

Comment: There's a bisection method right [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BisectionMethodFindRoot) . Use `bisect = ResourceFunction["BisectionMethodFindRoot"]`

Comment: +1 for `Method -> "Brent"`. It's a very robust method when you have a bracket of the root.

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the function you are using, and not in the `NSolve` or `FindRoot`. You need to make sure it can be evaluated numerically.

Comment: @Somos Yes, you are fully correct! flinty solved it for me in the comment to his answer below: If I check for the argument to be numeric `f[k_?NumericQ]:=...` it works with both, `NSolve` as well as `FindRoot`. Thank you, and thanks everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bisection method right [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BisectionMethodFindRoot).

Use `bisect = ResourceFunction["BisectionMethodFindRoot"]`

```
bisect = ResourceFunction["BisectionMethodFindRoot"];
f[x_] := Cosh[2 Sinh[x^3 - 1] Exp[-x^2]] - 3
root = bisect[f[x], {x, 0.25, 1.0}, 9, 10000]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {-2, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x /. root, 0}]}]
```

[image: point root bisection]

Comment: thanks a lot! You definitely answered my question, which is why I marked it as answer. ; )  Unfortunately I still get the error which I described in my starting post, also with the bisection method. It is really strange, since my function works as standalone function, but it doesn't work as function which is fed to `bisect`. The error which I get is happening in an `NDSolve` command which is nested inside my function. I will try to create a minimal example demonstrating this problem and open another thread for that. Anyway, thanks for the `bisect`!

Comment: @Britzel do you just need to pattern test the arguments of your function as `NumericQ` ? `f[x_?NumericQ] := ....` Based on that error `t$50961` I'd guess you have a Module in your function, correct?

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much! And yes, you were right, my function contained a `Module`, and in that module a set of ODEs was solved with `NDSolve`. The error occurred in `NDSolve`. So just that I understand what was going on: The way I defined my function it did not check for the argument to be numeric. And when plugging it into `NSolve`or `FindRood`, it somehow got non-numerical values passed, which led to the error? Anyway, thank you so much!!